# GeForce 6800 fan speed control; nvclock segmentation fault

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, fancontrol

I recently did an update on my Ubuntu 11.04.
Unfortunately I can't remember what was updated, but I am sure there were some core things.
Anyway, before that update I could change the fan speed, due it's heavy loudness, with an application called `nvclock`.
When I try to use it now with:
`nvclock -f -F 70`

I only get following reply:
`Segmentation fault`

So how can I get it back working, because it's really annoying loud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GF6800 on Ubuntu 10.04, i have the same problem. My workaround to change GPU fan speed is:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

in section "Device" add

```
Option       "Coolbits" "5"
```

Restart the PC. Then you can control fan speed with this command:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1
```

and then:

```
nvidia-settings -a [fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed=30
```

where 30 is a number from 1 to 100 % of fan speed.

You can set that two commands in Startup Applications to run at boot, remember it if your  GPU overheates.

Cheers

Comment: I recently downgraded my graphics driver, so `nvclock` worked again. But thanks for that trick.